# How does the minimum size work on detected rectangle using VNDetectRectanglesRequest?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-vision

Can you please explain how the `minimumSize` property of `VNDetectRectanglesRequest` works. I read the details but did not understand it.

[Description from the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/vndetectrectanglesrequest/2875374-minimumsize)

A float specifying the minimum size of the rectangle to be detected, as a proportion of the smallest dimension.

I did not understand “as a proportion of the smallest dimension”.

Also how many maximum rectangles vision framework can return? The comment inside apple sample code (demo app), they have written vision framework returns maximum 16 rectangles. Can anyone please confirm?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have the same question, and can’t seem to find an explanation anywhere...

Comment: I'm still looking for a concrete explanation.

Comment: about 'how many', you can set maximumObservation option 0 for unlimited rectangles. here's description from VNDetectRectanglesRequest code 'Specifies the maximum number of rectangles to be returned.  The default is 1.  Setting this property to 0 will allow an unlimited number of observations to be returned'

Answer (score 0):

It is the minimal share of the *screen* that the smaller side of the potential rectangle needs to take up, before Vision detects it.

Practically:
How near must a rectangle be to be detected?